# How do I get Split Screen to work on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a 6th generation iPad running iOS 12.2. I have tried Split Screen (as described in [Use Multitasking on your iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207582)), but can't seem to get it to work.

1. Open an app.
2. Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to reveal the Dock.
3. On the Dock, touch and hold the second app that you want to open, then drag it off the Dock.
4. When the app opens in Slide Over, drag the dash icon down.

After point #2, I see the Dock (and a normal home screen) - not sure if this is intended. When I try point #3, it just seems to rearrange apps on the Home screen.

I have Multitasking features turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you swipe up, swipe up just a little so the dock shows. If you swipe up too much, it'll open the multitasking view or the homescreen, which isn't what you want. You need to be in an app the entire time for it to work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any method to enable the split screen feature as top-bottom instead of left-right?